# Evaluation of symbolic computation not yielding exactly the same values as numpy calculation

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am facing an weird issue. I am making symbolic computations with sympy as afterwards the same calculation with numpy.

In some cases when I compare the results their do not have a negligible difference. Take for instance:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
import random as random

e11, e12, e13, e22, e23, e33 = sym.symbols("E11 E12 E13 E22 E23 E33")

E = sym.Matrix([[e11,e12,e13], [e12, e22, e23], [e13, e23, e33]])
for i in range(30):
    E_numeric = np.array([[random.uniform(0,10), random.uniform(-10,10),random.uniform(-10,10)],
                          [0, random.uniform(0,10), random.uniform(-10,10)],
                          [0,0, random.uniform(0,10)]])
        
    E_numeric[1,0] = E_numeric[0,1] 
    E_numeric[2,0] = E_numeric[0,2]
    E_numeric[2,1] = E_numeric[1,2]
    
    subsDict={e11:E_numeric[0,0], e12:E_numeric[0,1],
              e13:E_numeric[0,2], e22:E_numeric[1,1],
              e23:E_numeric[1,2], e33:E_numeric[2,2]}
    
    tst1 = np.linalg.det(E_numeric) - E.det().subs(subsDict)
    
    print("run: %s" %(i))
    if (np.any(tst1 > 1e-13)):
        print("Problems")
        break
```

Why is it yielding a different value? Is it the numpy routine doing something different?
Is it possible to predefined the number of decimal cases to store between both python modules in order to get comparable results?

Answer (score 0):

Both calculations give similar results in my testing:

```
In [5]: E.det().subs(subsDict)
Out[5]: -631.965803142996

In [6]: np.linalg.det(E_numeric)
Out[6]: -631.9658031429959
```

Since the result is of order 1e3 the rounding error from 53 bit floating point can be expected to be *at least* around 1e-13:

```
In [7]: 1e3/2**53
Out[7]: 1.1102230246251565e-13
```

It's not surprising that your check for an error greater than `1e-13` fails sometimes.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to increase the precision? and why a 53bit? shouldn't it be 64?

Comment: You can increase the precision of SymPy but not numpy. 64 bit floating point has 53 bits of precision.